# How do Install ROS Gazebo on Pop!_OS 20.10 x86_64 Codename:groovy

Tags: linux, simulation, ros

tried the following getting this on terminal

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

also followed all this steps still i cant find it
my pop os code name is Groovy apparently all of the codenames have different package names which are suitable plz help me find the correct one

Comment: Please describe what staps have you followed, Describe why you execute the commands you execute.

Answer (score 0):

The Pop!_OS 20.10 distribution is based on Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy) and has similar packages/dependencies versions accordingly.

ROS Kinetic Kame, you've tried to install, supports at max Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) so couldn't be installed on 20.10-based Ubuntu distribution because of dependencies.

The latest version of ROS (Noetic Ninjemys) officially supported on Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) and should work on Pop!_OS 20.04. So, to install ROS you have the following options:

1. Downgrade your OS to 16.04
2. Downgrade your OS to 20.04 and use ROS Noetic
3. Use Linux containers on the current OS 20.10 to solve OS/ROS compatibility issue.